# Replacing placeholders with dictionary keys/values

Tags: python, python-re

I have text with placeholders like:

`sometext $plc_hldr1 some more text $plc_hldr2 some more more text $1234date_placeholder some text $5678date_placeholder`

Then I have dictionary, where keys represents placeholders and value is the value by which the placeholders should be replaced by:

```
placeholders = {'$plc_hldr1': '1111',
                '$plc_hldr2': 'abcd'}
```

I found and adjusted the function to process the replacement:

```
def multiple_replace(adict, text):
   # Create a regular expression from all of the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, adict.keys(  ))))

   # For each match, look up the corresponding value in the dictionary
   return regex.sub(lambda match: adict[match.group(0)], text)
```

The function is doing it's job for `$plc_hldr1`  and `$plc_hldr2`.

But there are `$1234date_placeholder` and `$5678date_placeholder` - both should be replaced with one predefined value. In those case `date_placeholder` stays the same but number part is always different.

What I came up with is:

```
def multiple_replace(adict, text):
   # Create a regular expression from all of the dictionary keys
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, adict.keys(  ))))
    regex = re.sub("\$\d*date_placeholder", "20200101", txt)
   # For each match, look up the corresponding value in the dictionary
   return regex.sub(lambda match: adict[match.group(0)], text)
```

But is there more elegant way of doing that? In case I have some more placeholders with variable numeric part which should be replaced by the same value (eg $1234dname_placeholder, $1234age_placeholder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `\$\d*date_placeholder` with the rest of the placeholders, IF the rest of the placeholders do not need to be escaped. Then, create a second dictionary without any of the special regular expression characters, to use when looking up what to replace a regex match with.

`map(re.escape, adict.keys())` is necessary in your code above since you have the special regex character `$` in the placeholder names. I would recommend adding the special character escapes yourself, and adding your `\$\d*date_placeholder` lookup as a key/value pair in `placeholders`. This removes both the need to map `re.escape` over your keys and the need to use a second substitution in the `multiple_replace` function.

Like so...

```py
import re

placeholders = {r'\$plc_hldr1': '1111',
                r'\$plc_hldr2': 'abcd',
                r'\$\d*date_placeholder': '20200101'}

def remove_escape_chars(reggie):
    return re.sub(r'\\\$\\d\*|\$\d*|\\', '', reggie)

def multiple_replace(escape_dict, text):
   # Create a second dictionary to lookup regex match replacement targets
   unescaped_placeholders = { remove_escape_chars(k): placeholders[k] for k in placeholders }

   # Create a regular expression from all of the dictionary keys
   regex = re.compile("|".join(escape_dict.keys()))
   return regex.sub(lambda match: unescaped_placeholders[remove_escape_chars(match.group(0))], text)

text = "sometext $plc_hldr1 some more text $plc_hldr2 some more more text $1234date_placeholder some text $5678date_placeholder"

result = multiple_replace(placeholders, text)
print(result)
```

The downside of this approach is the fact you would have to update the regex in the `remove_escape_chars(...)` function if you introduced a new pattern into placeholders. (It WILL extend to similar patterns, such as `$1234dname_placeholder` or `$1234age_placeholder`.)