# regex issues with replacing placeholders dictionary key values

Tags: python, regex

This is with the reference to question:
[Replacing placeholders with dictionary keys/values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444057/replacing-placeholders-with-dictionary-keys-values)

I have placeholders (the same as in the referenced question except the last one). There I need to replace placeholder `$fil_TABLE_NAME1`, where `$fil_` stays the same but table name differs (split with underscores, can contain numbers)

```
placeholders = {r'\$plc_hldr1': '1111',
                r'\$plc_hldr2': 'abcd',
                r'\$\d*date_placeholder': '20200101',
                r'\$fil_\w+': '(select * from table)'
                }
```

For replacement I'm using the adjusted code from the referenced question

```
def remove_escape_chars(reggie):
     return re.sub(r'\\\$\\d\*|\$\d*|\\\$fil\\\_\\\w\\\+|\\', '', reggie)   #modification

def multiple_replace(escape_dict, text):
   # Create a second dictionary to lookup regex match replacement targets
   unescaped_placeholders = { remove_escape_chars(k): placeholders[k] for k in placeholders }

   # Create a regular expression from all of the dictionary keys
   regex = re.compile("|".join(escape_dict.keys()))
   return regex.sub(lambda match: unescaped_placeholders[remove_escape_chars(match.group(0))], text)
```

But when I execute it with

```
text = "sometext $fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME some more text $plc_hldr2 some more more text 
1234date_placeholder some text $5678date_placeholder"

result = multiple_replace(placeholders, text)
print(result)
```

I get   `sometext $fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME some more text abcd some more more text 20200101 some text 20200101` -  `$fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME` is not replaced.

I think I have some issue in regular expression, maybe something incorrectly escaped, but after several modifications, I was not able to find the issue.

Would anybody help me please?

Comment: I would like to get `sometext (select * from table) some more text abcd some more more text 20200101 some text 20200101` as result

Comment: When I run your code I get `KeyError: 'fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME'`. If you print `unescaped_placeholders`, it contains `'fil_w+': '(select * from table)'`. That won't be found with `unescaped_placeholders['fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME']`

Comment: you can't use a dictionary whose keys are regular expressions to look up the strings that are matched by it. The best I can think of is to loop through the dictionary, checking if `match.group(0)` is matched by the key, then return that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach to this. Rather than trying to match the regex which matched part of the string, create a regex which has each individual regex in its own group, and then use the matching group number to look up the replacement value. For your sample data, the regex would look like this:

```regex
(\$plc_hldr1)|(\$plc_hldr2)|(\$\d*date_placeholder)|(\$fil_\w+)
```

and the python code would then be:

```py
placeholders = {r'\$plc_hldr1': '1111',
                r'\$plc_hldr2': 'abcd',
                r'\$\d*date_placeholder': '20200101',
                r'\$fil_\w+': '(select * from table)'
                }
replacements = list(placeholders.values())

text = "sometext $fil_SAMPLE_TABLE_NAME some more text $plc_hldr2 some more more text $1234date_placeholder some text $5678date_placeholder"

regex = re.compile('(' + ')|('.join(placeholders.keys()) + ')')
regex.sub(lambda m: replacements[m.lastindex-1], text)
```

Output:

```
sometext (select * from table) some more text abcd some more more text 20200101 some text 20200101
```

Note that this requires that any group in any of the placeholder regexes needs to be non-capturing i.e. `(?:...)` rather than `(...)`.